# Test and Create File path

Tags: powershell

The basic idea:

1. Mirror the directory structure of the target path
2. Search the target path for files and folders of a certain age and create a text file with all the paths.
3. Read the previous text file and copy the contents of the different paths to a new drive location.

**Script 1** - Mirror the directory structure of the target path from drive to the next. This I feel like I have working pretty decently.

```
$target = Read-Host "What is the target path?"
$destination = "Z:\This\Is\The\Destination"

Copy-Item $target -Filter {PSIsContainter} -Recurse -Destination $destination -Force
```

**Script 2** - Is used to look through the $target path and looks for files and folders that are `-ge` `-le` `-eq` a `lastwritetime`, then outputs the locations in a text file.

```
$path = read-host "What path would you like to search?"
$daysOLD = read-host "How many days old should the files I'm looking for be?"
$outfile = "C:\locationOFtheTEXTfile\ReadThis.txt"
$today = Get-Date
$targetdate = $today.AddDays(-$daysOLD).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')

$files = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse| Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy') -le $targetdate} | ForEach-Object {$_.fullname}| out-file $outfile
```

**Script 3** - Is where I am having an issue. I know that I can use `Get-Content` and point to the location of the text file. What I have a hard time with is having the script read the file, test the path, and not create duplicates in the `$destination`.

Since I mirrored the directory structure with the first path, I just need the third script to move files to their appropriate folders on the new drive.

```
$dest = "Z:\This\Is\The\Destination"
$safe = Get-Content "C:\locationOFtheTEXTfile\ReadThis.txt" 
$safe | ForEach-Object{
    #find drive-delimeter
    $first=$_.IndexOf(":\");
    if($first -eq 1){
        #stripe it
        $newdes=Join-Path -Path $dest -ChildPath @($_.Substring(0,1)+$_.Substring(2))[0]
    } else {
        $newdes=Join-Path -Path $des -ChildPath $_
    }
    $folder = Split-Path -Path $newdes -Parent
    $err=0
    #check if folder exists"
    $void=Get-Item $folder -ErrorVariable err  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if($err.Count -ne 0){
        #create when it doesn't
        $void=New-Item -Path $folder -ItemType Directory -Force -Verbose
    }
    $void=Copy-Item -Path $_ -destination $newdes -Recurse -Container -Force -Verbose
}

write-host "Doomsday =("
```

This script was taken from the web and I haven't had a chance to figure it's parts and pieces for myself. I know that sound pathetic but I don't feel like trying to reinvent the wheel is necessary.

Comment: Well I think one issue is converting proper dates to strings in Script2 and then try to compare them. Remove the two occurences of `.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')`

Comment: This sounds like trying to reinvent [Robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.11).aspx). It can even react to source directory changes.

Comment: I think he wants some logging to a text file and date filtering, which RC can't do. - When you say you don't want to copy duplicates, what are your qualifiers? Just the name, the size, etc.? How will the script (or person) know it's a true duplicate?

Comment: Robocopy can create a log file output with the `/log` switch. It also has `/maxage` and `/minage` switches that can be used to do date filtering.

Comment: I sit corrected. I know it creates logs, but I like the flexibility of *what* is being logged. I wasn't aware of the date filtering though, good to know.

Comment: @RMHaley I don't want to create duplicates. I apologize if that's not super clear. When I run  script 1 it'll create the directory structure. When I finally get to script 3 it creates duplicate copies of the folder structure, while totally ignoring what is there. Basically, I'm trying to figure out a way for the script to compare the paths in the text file and compare them to the new destination.

At any rate, I appreciate yall responding.

Comment: Instead of Get-Item, try Test-Path - It's faster and returns a Boolean which is great for IF statements